# Two textview in frame layout?

Tags: android, textview, android-framelayout

WhiteSpace character is not same as text character .
How to solve this?

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

<TextView
android:textSize="12sp"
android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
android:id="@+id/tv_tag"
android:textColor="@color/dark_indigo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
android:textSize="12sp"
android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
android:id="@+id/tv_content"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Java:

```
String tag = "#" + modelReply.getTag();
tv_tag.setText(tag);
String startSpace = "";
for(int j = 0; j <= tag.length(); j++){
startSpace += " ";
}
String content = startSpace + modelReply.getComment_content();

tv_content.setText(content);
```

First textview style is different from second style. So I placed them in frameLayout. But two textview's overllaping..

Edit:
I want to show two textview as one textview.

Comment: Define layout_gravity

Comment: This `String startSpace = "";` looks like it is a empty String, not a Space

Comment: Does it need to be a FrameLayout for some reason? I pretty much only use FrameLayout when I want things to overlap. Why not use a LinearLayout, for example?